# aggregate with {$out:"test1"} fails with test1 is not defined

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My command won't create a collection. This article says that $out will create a collection if it doesn't exist:  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

The article has square brackets that I didn't include, but all my aggregate functions have been working without the square brackets and I get the same error with or without them.

THE COMMAND

> mongo localhost/UW --quiet -eval "db.Test_Structures.aggregate( {
>   $project: { _id: 1 , edited_on: 1} }, { $out : "test1" } )"

THE ERROR

> 2018-11-27T18:55:27.677-0800 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError:
>   test1 is not defined : @(shell eval):1:74

By comparison, THE COMMAND

> mongo localhost/UW --quiet -eval "db.Test_Structures.aggregate( {
>   $project: { _id: 1 , edited_on: 1} } )" > C:\MyTest.txt

THE OUTPUT

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5aaa1d85b8078250f1000c0e"), "edited_on" :
>   ISODate("2018-03-15T07:15:17.583Z") }

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have quotes inside quotes:

```
mongo localhost/UW --quiet -eval "db.Test_Structures.aggregate( { $project: { _id: 1 , edited_on: 1} }, { $out : "test1" } )"
```

Try changing `"test1"` to `'test1'` like so:

```
mongo localhost/UW --quiet -eval "db.Test_Structures.aggregate( { $project: { _id: 1 , edited_on: 1} }, { $out : 'test1' } )"
```